Migrate Algorithm using latest IBM Qiskit SKD (v1.2.4) for Python
I am looking for an implementation of an algorithm using the IBM Qiskit SDK for Python.
I know that there is an implementation for Qiskit v0.x but I am missing an implementation for the current/latest Qiskit version (v1.x). I tried migrating the Qiskit v0.x function to Qiskit version v1.x using the IBM Qiskit Mitigation Guide but I had multiple troubles figuring out how to migrate certain imports, e.g. for qiskit.providers and qiskit.utils.
Has anyone already successfully migrated an algorithm to the latest version of Qiskit; or does anyone know of a project which did this already? I was searching for it online but didn't find anything.

I put some comments and a figure for clarification on the code.
screen_N() : screens given N, I used the Miller-Rabin primality test to check if N is prime.
continued_fraction() : generates a continued fraction terms from a real number(theta) calculated by QPE
convCf2F() : convert a continued fraction terms to a fraction form x/y, integer numerator(x) and denominator(y)
extended_gcd() : calcuates an inverse of a mod N by extended euclidean algorithm
serialize_2n() : serializes 2n control qubits into 1 control qubit by iteratively applying inverse QFT and doing measurement on the single control qubit
factor_integer() : main function to factor N
isSim : set True for AerSimulator, False for a real device
circuitOpt : set True for 2n+3 qubit optimization, False for 4n+2 qubit usage
This figure explains what serializing part(serialize_2n) does :

Here's the code :
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:


from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, ClassicalRegister, QuantumRegister, transpile
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator, Aer
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService
from qiskit.circuit import Parameter
from qiskit.circuit.library import RZGate
from qiskit import qpy
from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import Session, SamplerV2 as Sampler

import numpy as np
import math
import random
import time
import pandas as pd
from numpy import pi

service = QiskitRuntimeService()
device_backend  = QiskitRuntimeService().least_busy(operational=True, dynamic_circuits=True)
#device_backend  = QiskitRuntimeService().backend('ibm_brisbane')#least_busy(operational=True, dynamic_circuits=True)

print("backend: ", device_backend.name)
print("Number of qubits:", device_backend.configuration().n_qubits)


# In[2]:


from qiskit.circuit.classical import expr
def condition_to_expr(reg, value):
    return expr.lift(reg) if value else expr.logic_not(reg)


# In[3]:


def continued_fraction(v, iter_num=5):
    terms = []
    if iter_num <= 0:
        return terms
    a = 0
    x = v
    for i in range(iter_num):
        a = np.floor(x)
        terms.append(a)
        frac = x - a
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        # if frac is close to zero then break
        if math.isclose(frac, 0, abs_tol=1e-09):
            break
        x = 1/frac
    return terms    


# In[4]:


# P_-1 = 1, P_0 = a0, Q_0 = 1, Q_-1 = 0
# numerator;   P_n = an * P_n-1 + P_n-2
# denominator; Q_n = an * Q_n-1 + Q_n-2
def convCf2F(cf):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    r = False
    cf_size = len(cf)
    PArr = []
    QArr = []
    Pn = 0 # numerator
    Qn = 1 # denominator
    if cf_size == 0:
        return r, Pn, Qn
    elif cf_size == 1:
        Pn = cf[0]
        Qn = 1
        return True, Pn, Qn
    elif cf_size == 2:
        Pn = cf[1] * (cf[0]) + 1
        Qn = cf[1] * 1 + 0
        return True, Pn, Qn

    # set P0, P1, Q0, Q1
    PArr.append(cf[0]) #P0
    PArr.append(cf[1] * (cf[0]) + 1) #P1
    QArr.append(1) #Q0
    QArr.append(cf[1] * 1 + 0) #Q1
    # calculate Pn, Qn for n >= 2
    for idx in range(2, cf_size):
        Pn = cf[idx]*PArr[idx-1]+PArr[idx-2]
        Qn = cf[idx]*QArr[idx-1]+QArr[idx-2]
        PArr.append(Pn)
        QArr.append(Qn)
    return True, Pn, Qn


# In[5]:


a = [3,1,3]
result = convCf2F(a)
print(result)


# In[6]:


def gcd(a, b):
    #print(a,b)
    if a == 0:
        return b
    if b == 0:
        return a
    return gcd(b, a%b)


# In[7]:


# apply inverse phase shift rotation gates in recursive 
def inv_qft_rotation(circuit, n, m, q):
    if n==0:
        return circuit
    # get theta index for rotation
    l = range(2, m-n+2)
    revl = list(l)[::-1]# reverse the order of the list

    control_idx = 0
    n-=1
        
    for k in revl:
        circuit.cp(-pi/2**(k-1), q[control_idx], q[m-n-1])
        control_idx+=1
    circuit.h(q[m-n-1])
    return inv_qft_rotation(circuit, n, m, q)


# In[8]:


def inv_qft_rotation_simple(circuit, n, m, q, c):
    if n==0:
        return circuit
    # get theta index for rotation
    l = range(2, m-n+2)
    revl = list(l)[::-1]

    control_idx = 0
    n-=1

    angle = 0
    # calculate a sum of angles applied 
    for k in revl:
        #circuit.p(-pi/2**(k-1), q).c_if(c[control_idx], 1)
        with circuit.if_test(condition_to_expr(c[control_idx], 1)):
            circuit.p(-pi/2**(k-1), q)        
        control_idx+=1
    # apply hadamard gate
    circuit.h(q)


# In[9]:


# apply phase shift rotation gates in recursive 
def qft_rotation(circuit, n, q):
    if n==0:
        return circuit
    n-=1
    circuit.h(q[n])
    control_idx = n-1
    for k in range(2, n+2):
        circuit.cp(pi/2**(k-1), q[control_idx], q[n])
        control_idx-=1
    return qft_rotation(circuit, n, q)


# In[10]:


# apply qft transform
def qft(circuit, n, q, swap=True):
    qft_rotation(circuit, n, q)
    if swap:
        qft_swap(circuit, n, q)


# In[11]:


# apply swap gates
def qft_swap(circuit, n, q):
    # num of times of swap
    swap_num = (int)(n/2)
    m = n-1
    for i in range(swap_num):
        circuit.swap(q[i], q[m])
        m -= 1 


# In[12]:


def swap_classical_reg(c):
    for i in range(len(c)//2):
        # Swap the values of bits i and len(c)-1-i
        c[i], c[len(c)-1-i] = c[len(c)-1-i], c[i]


# In[13]:


# apply inverse qft transform
def inv_qft(circuit, n, m, q, swap=True):
    if swap:
        qft_swap(circuit, n, q)
    inv_qft_rotation(circuit, n, m, q)


# In[14]:


# addr gate; n qubits
def addr(circuit, q, n, a, ctrl1=None, ctrl2=None):
    #qc = QuantumCircuit(n, name="addr")
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    if ctrl1 is None and ctrl2 is None:
        # normal addr
        for i in range(n):
            circuit.rz(2*np.pi*a/2**(i+1), q[i])
    elif ctrl1 is not None and ctrl2 is None:
        # singly controlled addr
        for i in range(n):
            circuit.cp(2*np.pi*a/2**(i+1), ctrl1, q[i])
    elif ctrl1 is not None and ctrl2 is not None:
        # doubly controlled addr
        for i in range(n):
            gate = RZGate(2*np.pi*a/2**(i+1))
            circuit.append(gate.control(2), [ctrl1, ctrl2, q[i]])
    else:
        # invalid param
        print("invalid param")


# In[15]:


def subtract(circuit, q, n, a, ctrl1=None, ctrl2=None):
    if ctrl1 is None and ctrl2 is None:
        # normal subtract
        for i in range(n):
            circuit.rz(-2*np.pi*a/2**(i+1), q[i])
    elif ctrl1 is not None and ctrl2 is None:
        # singly controlled subtract
        for i in range(n):
            circuit.cp(-2*np.pi*a/2**(i+1), ctrl1, q[i])
    elif ctrl1 is not None and ctrl2 is not None:
        # doubly controlled subtract
        for i in range(n):
            gate = RZGate(-2*np.pi*a/2**(i+1))
            circuit.append(gate.control(2), [ctrl1, ctrl2, q[i]])
    else:
        # invalid param
        print("invalid param")


# In[16]:


# modular addr gate; n+2 qubits
def mod_addr(circuit, q, ctrl1, ctrl2, aux, a, N, n):
    #1. doubly controlled addr(a)
    addr(circuit, q, n, a, ctrl1, ctrl2)
    #2. subtract(N)
    subtract(circuit, q, n, N, None, None)
    #3. Inverse QFT
    inv_qft(circuit, n, n, q, False)
    #4. CNOT
    circuit.cx(q[n-1], aux)
    #5. QFT
    qft(circuit, n, q, False)
    #6. singly controlled addr(N)
    addr(circuit, q, n, N, aux, None)
    #7. doubly controlled subtract(a)
    subtract(circuit, q, n, a, ctrl1, ctrl2)
    #8. Inverse QFT
    inv_qft(circuit, n, n, q, False)  
    #9. NOT
    circuit.x(q[n-1])
    #10. CNOT
    circuit.cx(q[n-1], aux)
    #11. NOT
    circuit.x(q[n-1])
    #12. QFT
    qft(circuit, n, q, False)
    #13. doubly controlled addr(a)
    addr(circuit, q, n, a, ctrl1, ctrl2)


# In[17]:


# inverse modular addr gate; n+2 qubits
def inv_mod_addr(circuit, q, ctrl1, ctrl2, aux, a, N, n):
    #13. doubly controlled subtract(a)
    subtract(circuit, q, n, a, ctrl1, ctrl2)
    #12. Inv QFT
    inv_qft(circuit, n, n, q, False)
    #11. NOT
    circuit.x(q[n-1])
    #10. CNOT
    circuit.cx(q[n-1], aux)
    #9. NOT
    circuit.x(q[n-1])
    #8. QFT
    qft(circuit, n, q, False)  
    #7. doubly controlled addr(a)
    addr(circuit, q, n, a, ctrl1, ctrl2)
    #6. singly controlled subtract(N)
    subtract(circuit, q, n, N, aux, None)
    #5. Inv QFT
    inv_qft(circuit, n, n, q, False)
    #4. CNOT
    circuit.cx(q[n-1], aux)
    #3. QFT
    qft(circuit, n, q, False)
    #2. addr(N)
    addr(circuit, q, n, N, None, None)
    #1. doubly controlled subtract(a)
    subtract(circuit, q, n, a, ctrl1, ctrl2)    


# In[18]:


# Controlled Multiplication(CMULT) gate; 2n+2 qubits
def c_mult(circuit, ctrl, q, aux, a, N, n):
    #1. QFT
    qft(circuit, n+1, aux, False)
    #2. apply n modular addrs
    for i in range(0, n):
        mod_addr(circuit, aux, q[i], ctrl, aux[n+1], ((2**i)*a)%N, N, n+1)
    #3. Inverse QFT
    inv_qft(circuit, n+1, n+1, aux, False)


# In[19]:


# Inverse Controlled Multiplication(CMULT) gate; 2n+2 qubits
def inv_c_mult(circuit, ctrl, q, aux, a, N, n):
    #1. QFT
    qft(circuit, n+1, aux, False)
    #2. apply n modular addrs
    for i in range(0, n):
        idx = n-1-i
        inv_mod_addr(circuit, aux, q[idx], ctrl, aux[n+1], ((2**idx)*a)%N, N, n+1)
    #3. Inverse QFT
    inv_qft(circuit, n+1, n+1, aux, False)


# In[20]:


# General Unitary Operator(Ua); 2n + 2
def gen_ua(circuit, ctrl, eigen_vec_reg, aux, a, N, n):
    #1. CMULT(a) mod N
    c_mult(circuit, ctrl, eigen_vec_reg, aux, a, N, n)

    #2. SWAP
    for i in range(0, n):
        circuit.cswap(ctrl, eigen_vec_reg[i], aux[i])

    #calculate modular inverse
    a_mod_inv = mod_inverse(a, N)
     
    #3. CMULT(a^-1) mod N
    inv_c_mult(circuit, ctrl, eigen_vec_reg, aux, a_mod_inv, N, n)


# In[21]:


def extended_gcd(a, b):
    if a == 0:
        return b, 0, 1
    else:
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        gcd, x, y = extended_gcd(b % a, a)
        #return gcd, y - np.floor(b/a) * x, x
        return gcd, y - b//a * x, x


# In[22]:


def mod_inverse(a, m):
    gcd, x, _ = extended_gcd(a, m)
    if gcd != 1:
        print(f"The modular inverse does not exist for {a} modulo {m}.")
    else:
        return x % m


# In[23]:


# choose a randomly 2 <= a <= N-1
def choose_random_a(N):
    return random.randint(2, N - 1)


# In[24]:


def factor_integer(N, isSim=True, circuitOpt=False):
    MAX_ITER_REAL_DEVICE = 1
    MAX_ITER_SIM = 10
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    print("### running on a simulator ###" if isSim else "### running on a real device ###")
    # screen N
    result, p, q = screen_N(N)
    if result:
        return result, p, q
    
    n = math.ceil(math.log(N,2))
    print("### Let's factor N = {0} ###".format(N))
    print("n={0}".format(n))
    
    max_iter = MAX_ITER_SIM if isSim else MAX_ITER_REAL_DEVICE
    a = 2 #default a
    
    for count in range(max_iter):
        #set registers
        #aux register; n+2 qubits
        aux_reg = QuantumRegister(n+2, name="aux")
        #eigen vector register; n qubits
        eigen_vec_reg = QuantumRegister(n, name="eigen vec")

        counting_reg = None
        counting_reg_1qubit = None

        # counting register; 2n or 1 qubit
        if circuitOpt:
            #counting register; 1 qubit
            counting_reg_1qubit = QuantumRegister(1, name="counting_1_qubit")
        else:
            #counting register; 2n qubits
            counting_reg = QuantumRegister(2*n, name="counting_2n_qubit")
        #classical register; 2n qubits
        classic_reg = ClassicalRegister(2*n, name="classic")
        
        #create quantum circuit
        circuit = 0
        if circuitOpt:
            circuit = QuantumCircuit(eigen_vec_reg, aux_reg, counting_reg_1qubit, classic_reg)
        else:
            circuit = QuantumCircuit(counting_reg, eigen_vec_reg, aux_reg, classic_reg)
            circuit.h(counting_reg)
        
        print("The total number of qubits used : {0}".format(circuit.num_qubits))        
        #initialize eigen vector to |00..001> and counting register to superposition        
        circuit.x(eigen_vec_reg[0])

        # 1: choose a randomly ranging between 2 and N-1 
        a = choose_random_a(N)
        
        print("# of iteration = {0}, a = {1}".format(count, a))
        # 2: calculate gcd(a, N)
        d = gcd(a, N)
        # 3: if d >= 2 then return the factor
        if d >= 2:
            print("we're lucky, factoring is done. ")
            return True, d, (int)(N/d)
        # 4: run an order finding algo on QC
        else:
            print("Let's run order finding algorithm to find r on QC.")
            if circuitOpt:
                serialize_2n(circuit, counting_reg_1qubit, eigen_vec_reg, aux_reg, classic_reg, a, N, n)
            else:
                # apply Ua gate
                # use the property : ((a^n) * x) mod N = (a..(a(ax)mod N)mod N)..)mod N)
                # we don't need to apply Ua gate n-times to get (Ua)^n because we can directly
                # run Ua^n(where a^n mod N in computed classically) which i sthe same sas (Ua)^n 
                for i in range(2*n):
                    # we compute a^(2^i) classically
                    gen_ua(circuit, counting_reg[i], eigen_vec_reg, aux_reg, int(pow(a, pow(2, i))), N, n)
                # apply inverse QFT
                inv_qft(circuit, 2*n, 2*n, counting_reg, True)
                # measure counting register
                circuit.measure(counting_reg, classic_reg)
            
            # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            print("circuit depth : {0}".format(circuit.depth()))
            #ircuit.measure()   classic_reg_for_1qubit
            # with open('shor.qpy', 'wb') as fd:
            #     qpy.dump(circuit, fd)
            shots = 10
            backend = None
            if isSim:
                backend = AerSimulator()
            else:
                backend = device_backend
            print("backend = {0}".format(backend.name))
            
            #t_qc = transpile(circuit, backend)
            job = None
            #if circuitOpt and not isSim:
            # if circuitOpt:
            #     print("dynamic=True")
            #     job = backend.run(t_qc, shots=shots, dynamic=True)
            # else:
            #     job = backend.run(t_qc, shots = shots)
            
            
            pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(backend=backend, optimization_level=3)
            isa_qc = pm.run(circuit)

            sampler = Sampler(backend)
            job = sampler.run([isa_qc], shots=shots)
            # with Session(backend=backend) as session:
            #     sampler = Sampler(mode=session)
            #     job = sampler.run([isa_qc], shots=shots)
            print("jobId:{0}".format(job.job_id()))
            pub_result = job.result()[0]
            counts = pub_result.data.classic.get_counts()            
            #counts = job.result().get_counts()

            rows, measured_phases = [], []
            for output in counts:
                decimal = int(output, 2)  # Convert (base 2) string to decimal
                phase = decimal/(2**(2*n))  # Find corresponding eigenvalue
                measured_phases.append(phase)
                # Add these values to the rows in our table:
                rows.append([f"{output}(bin) = {decimal:>3}(dec)", 
                 f"{decimal}/{2**(2*n)} = {phase:.2f}"])
            # Print the rows in a table
            headers=["Register Output", "Phase"]
            df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=headers)
            print(df)
            print('\n')
            rows = []
            for phase in measured_phases:
                terms = continued_fraction(phase)
                result = convCf2F(terms)
                if(result):
                    rows.append([phase, f"{result[1]}/{result[2]}", result[2]])
            # Print as a table
            headers=["Phase", "Fraction", "Guess for r"]
            df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=headers)
            print(df)
            print('\n')
            # parse through the qcquired fractions and calculate factors
            for i in rows:
                r = i[2]
                print("r = {0}".format(r))
                if r%2==0: # r is even
                    exponent = (int)(r/2)
                    x = (int)((a**(exponent) -1) % N) # x = (a^(r/2) -1) mod N
                    y = (int)((a**(exponent) +1) % N) # y = (a^(r/2) +1) mod N

                    if y == 0:
                        print("({0}^({1}/2) +1) = 0 mod {2}".format(a, r, N))
                        continue
                    
                    p = (int)(gcd(x, N))  # p = gcd(x, N)
                    # check if p is a non-trivial factor of N.
                    if p >= 2 and p != N:
                        # found a factor
                        q = (int)(N/p)
                        print("## found factor! p = {0} q = {1} ##".format(p, q))
                        return True, p, q
    print("factorization failed {0}".format(count))
    return False, 0, 0


# In[25]:


# do some screening tests
def screen_N(N):
    if N <= 2: 
        # invalid N; N is less than or equal to 2
        print("N should be greater than 2.")
        return True, 0, 0

    if (N%2)==0:
        # N is even
        p = 2
        q = N/p
        print("N is even, factoring is done.")
        return True, p, q

    # check if N is a prime or prime power
    k = 4;# number of iterations
    if isPrime(N,k):
        print("{0} is a prime".format(N))
        return True, N, 1
    else:
        i, power = is_prime_power(N)
        if i is not None:
            # N is a prime power
            print("{0} is a prime power : {1} ^ {2}".format(N, i, power))
            return True, i, (int)(N/i)
    return False, 0, 0


# In[26]:


# program Miller-Rabin primality test(power, miillerTest)
# Reference : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/primality-test-set-3-miller-rabin/ 
def power(x, y, p):
    # Initialize result
    res = 1; 
     
    # Update x if it is more than or
    # equal to p
    x = x % p; 
    while (y > 0):
         
        # If y is odd, multiply
        # x with result
        if (y & 1):
            res = (res * x) % p;
 
        # y must be even now
        y = y>>1; # y = y/2
        x = (x * x) % p;
     
    return res;
 
# This function is called
# for all k trials. It returns
# false if n is composite and 
# returns false if n is
# probably prime. d is an odd 
# number such that d*2<sup>r</sup> = n-1
# for some r >= 1
def miillerTest(d, n):
     
    # Pick a random number in [2..n-2]
    # Corner cases make sure that n > 4
    a = 2 + random.randint(1, n - 4);
 
    # Compute a^d % n
    x = power(a, d, n);
 
    if (x == 1 or x == n - 1):
        return True;
 
    # Keep squaring x while one 
    # of the following doesn't 
    # happen
    # (i) d does not reach n-1
    # (ii) (x^2) % n is not 1
    # (iii) (x^2) % n is not n-1
    while (d != n - 1):
        x = (x * x) % n;
        d *= 2;
 
        if (x == 1):
            return False;
        if (x == n - 1):
            return True;
 
    # Return composite
    return False;
 
# It returns false if n is 
# composite and returns true if n
# is probably prime. k is an 
# input parameter that determines
# accuracy level. Higher value of 
# k indicates more accuracy.
def isPrime( n, k):
     
    # Corner cases
    if (n <= 1 or n == 4):
        return False;
    if (n <= 3):
        return True;
 
    # Find r such that n = 
    # 2^d * r + 1 for some r >= 1
    d = n - 1;
    while (d % 2 == 0):
        d //= 2;
 
    # Iterate given number of 'k' times
    for i in range(k):
        if (miillerTest(d, n) == False):
            return False;
 
    return True;


# In[27]:


# list all the primes between 2 and n
def sieve_of_eratosthenes(n):
    # prepare the list of numbers containing [0, 1, ..., n]
    numbers = list(range(n+1))
    numbers[0] = numbers[1] = 0 # mark 0 and 1 as non-prime(0)

    # the first prime is 2
    p = 2

    while p < n:
        if p:
            index = p + p
            while index <= n:
                numbers[index] = 0
                index += p
        p += 1

    # return the primes left in the list
    return [i for i in numbers if i != 0]


# In[28]:


# check if n is prime power
def is_prime_power(n):
    prime_list = sieve_of_eratosthenes(n)
    #print(prime_list)
    for i in prime_list:
        m = n
        power = 0
        while m % i == 0:
            m = math.floor(m/i)
            power += 1
        if m == 1:
            return i, power
    return None, None


# In[29]:


# make a one-qubit control circuit in which a series of inverse-QFT are applied
def serialize_2n(circuit, counting_reg_1qubit, eigen_vec_reg, aux_reg, classic_reg, a, N, n):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    m = 2*n
    for i in range(m):
        # apply a hadamard gate
        circuit.h(counting_reg_1qubit)
        # apply controlled Ua gate
        #gen_ua(circuit, counting_reg_1qubit, eigen_vec_reg, aux_reg, int(pow(a, pow(2, i))), N, n)
        gen_ua(circuit, counting_reg_1qubit, eigen_vec_reg, aux_reg, int(pow(a, pow(2, 2*n-1-i))), N, n)
        
        # apply inverse QFT

        # apply serialized inverse QFT on 1 qubit
        inv_qft_rotation_simple(circuit, m-i, m, counting_reg_1qubit, classic_reg)
        # measure
        circuit.measure(counting_reg_1qubit, classic_reg[i])
        
        # apply X if the measured qubit is 1
        with circuit.if_test(condition_to_expr(classic_reg[i],1)):
           circuit.x(counting_reg_1qubit)#.c_if(condition_to_expr(classic_reg[i],1))
        #circuit.x(counting_reg_1qubit).c_if(classic_reg[i],1)


# In[30]:


# declare N
N = 85
#N = 15

# use a real device or simulator
isSim = True

# optimize circuit to use only 2n+3 qubits
circuitOpt = True

# Seed the random number generator with the current time
random.seed(time.time())

r, p, q = factor_integer(N, isSim, circuitOpt)
if r :
    print("{0} = {1} x {2}".format(N, p, q))
    print("The factoring has succeeded.")
else:
    # failure
    print("The factoring failed")


# In[ ]:

A result for factoring N=85 :
### running on a simulator ###
### Let's factor N = 85 ###
n=7
The total number of qubits used : 17
# of iteration = 0, a = 48
Let's run order finding algorithm to find r on QC.
circuit depth : 15548
backend = aer_simulator
jobId:d6d70699-196d-4ef4-bfb5-d6905ee6e4a0
                    Register Output               Phase
0   01010000000000(bin) = 5120(dec)   5120/16384 = 0.31
1  11100000000000(bin) = 14336(dec)  14336/16384 = 0.88
2   10010000000000(bin) = 9216(dec)   9216/16384 = 0.56
3  10110000000000(bin) = 11264(dec)  11264/16384 = 0.69
4   01100000000000(bin) = 6144(dec)   6144/16384 = 0.38
5   00010000000000(bin) = 1024(dec)   1024/16384 = 0.06
6  10100000000000(bin) = 10240(dec)  10240/16384 = 0.62
7   10000000000000(bin) = 8192(dec)   8192/16384 = 0.50


    Phase   Fraction  Guess for r
0  0.3125   5.0/16.0         16.0
1  0.8750    7.0/8.0          8.0
2  0.5625   9.0/16.0         16.0
3  0.6875  11.0/16.0         16.0
4  0.3750    3.0/8.0          8.0
5  0.0625   1.0/16.0         16.0
6  0.6250    3.0/5.0          5.0
7  0.5000    1.0/2.0          2.0


r = 16.0
## found factor! p = 5 q = 17 ##
85 = 5 x 17
The factoring has succeeded.

Here's the references/resources I used to make the code :
[1]St ́ephane Beauregard, Circuit for Shor’s algorithm using 2n+3 qubits
[2]Thomas G. Draper, Addition on a Quantum Computer
[3]https://github.com/ttlion/ShorAlgQiskit/tree/master
[4]https://medium.com/mit-6-s089-intro-to-quantum-computing/a-general-implementation-of-shors-algorithm-da1595694430
[5]Robert S. Sutor, Dancing with Qubits by Robert S. Sutor
[6]John Watrous, Order finding
https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~watrous/QC-notes/QC-notes.10.pdf
[7]A.Ya. KHINCHIN, Continued fractions
[8]MICHAEL A. NIELSEN and ISAAC L .CHUANG, Quantum Computation and Quantum Information 10th Anniversary Edition
[9]Shor's algorithm Wikipedia,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm
[10]https://www.cs.umd.edu/~amchilds/talks/qalg.pdf


Thank you! I will work through the code over the next few days. What resources did you use for all the code?

I've added the resource list at the end of my answer, please take a look.

Thank you very much!

Hi @taketoshi - I would have one more question: does this code also run for you when isSim = True; so when using real quantum hardware from IBM? For me, it just loads and also on IBM Quantum, I cannot see that a job started there.

When isSim = True, then it uses AerSimulator(=a classical simulaoter) as its backend. If isSim = False then, it uses a real IBM backend device. Do you see any error message?

if you're asking if it runs a job on a real device with isSim=True then no it doesn't.

I had some issues with the token, maybe that was why it didn't work.
When running the code now I can see the job here.
I run it for N = 15 until it runs on the quantum HW. The job takes around 2s after queueing but sometimes I get the following output:
factorization failed 0
The factoring failed
Sometimes it also works.
Is this explainable due to quantum noise?

yes, you're exactly right. just use a simulator if you want a noiseless result.

As a part of screening we check if gcd(a, N)>=2 before  running an order finding. From your comment, "sometimes it also works", I just assume that a randomly picked 'a' was that stated case.
